# Logical contradiction type definitions

Tags: haskell, homework

(Homework alert)

Working my way through ["The Haskell Road..."](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/), not sure about my solution to exercise 2.15 on page 48 of the second edition:

> A propositional contradiction is a formula that yields false for every combination of truth values for its propositional letters. Write Haskell definitions of contradiction tests for propositional functions with one, two, and three variables.

I somehow gather from the way the question is asked that they expect something along the lines of:

```
contradiction_1 :: (Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
contradiction_1 f = (f True) == False && (f False) == False
```

and so on.

However, previously in the text it has been shown how to use a type class to implement validity and logical equivalence:

> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
>
> class TF p where
>   valid :: p -> Bool
>   lequiv :: p -> p -> Bool
>
> instance TF Bool where
>   valid = id
>   lequiv f g = f == g
>
> instance TF p => (Bool -> p) where
>   valid = valid (f True)
>        && valid (f False)
>   lequiv f g = lequiv (f True) (g True)
>             && lequiv (f False) (g False)
> ```

This above is all in the textbook.

So I thought that I can simply add the definition for contradiction as follows:

```
class TF p where
  valid :: p -> Bool
  contradiction :: p -> Bool -- added
  lequiv :: p -> p -> Bool

instance TF Bool where
  valid = id
  contradiction f = f == False -- added
  lequiv f g = f == g

instance TF p => (Bool -> p) where
  valid = valid (f True)
       && valid (f False)
  contradiction f = contradiction (f True) -- added
                 && contradiction (f False) -- added
  lequiv f g = lequiv (f True) (g True)
            && lequiv (f False) (g False)
```

This now is the code from the textbook, still unchanged, only with my additions.

It *seems* to work, in the sense that it only returns true for actual contradictions for what I've tried so far, for example, with GHCI:

```
*Main> contradiction (\p -> p && (not p))
True
*Main> contradiction (\p q -> (p || q) && ((not p) && (not q)))
True
*Main> contradiction (\p q r -> p && q && ((not p) && r))
True
```

But I have to admit that I really don't understand what **exactly** the code I wrote is doing (I did it with "pattern matching", if you know what I mean).

PS: I cannot tag the question as I would like because I don't have enough rep to create new tags.

Comment: This interests me, as I've been looking into both Haskell and theorem provers... I can't help much though, sorry. Two things I will suggest: **1.** It looks nice when you align things i.e. insert whitespace so that the `::` symbols line up. **2.** Instead of `contradiction f = f == false`, why not `contradiction = not.id`? This makes it the logical negation of `id`.

Comment: @Myridium I haven't written much Haskell code and I am still finding the most comfortable spacing/indenting style. The second suggestion though... "Contradiction" is meant to mean "formula is false for any combination of variable values", so I think the logical negation of id would be actually wrong?

Comment: `contradiction f = (f == False)` is applied to an instance of the typeclass `TF a` where `a => Bool` (`a` is of type `Bool`). This means that in that expression you have, `f` is simply a `Bool`-- it is either `True` or `False`. So in this case, I think all you want to do is take the negation of `f`.

Comment: @Myridium Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: I have never even written my own typeclass before; I'm hardly qualified to write an answer. However, if you want to enter a chat room and work together on understanding this, then I would be happy to do so.

Comment: @Myridium Changing to `contradiction = not.id` as you suggest doesn't brake it for my test cases. Still hoping to get an answer by someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, this is the first time I've used Typeclasses so someone feel free to slap me with a tuna if I mess something up.

First of all, I don't understand why the use of "FlexibleInstances" is necessary, and it scares me because these kinds of warnings are usually put in place for a reason. With that out of the way, I'll go through the code.

---

The first thing you should realize is that in Haskell, *typeclasses* are basically the same thing as Java's *interfaces*. They define a contract of behaviour which *instances* of the class must obey. In this case, the typeclass I'm calling `Prop` promises the user three methods:

1. `valid` to check if the proposition is logically valid (true for all possible inputs)
2. `contradiction` to check if the proposition is false for all possible inputs.
3. `lequiv` to check if two propositions of the same number of arguments have an identical truth value given the same inputs.

These correspond to three questions which we could ask of any proposition which is a function of any number of propositional atoms. In case you're unfamiliar with this terminology, an 'atom' is one of the inputs to a proposition which is a function taking some number of atoms and itself evaluating to either `True` or `False`.

### Typeclass Declaration

The name `TF` for the type class bears no meaning for me, so I changed it to `Prop` short for "Proposition".

```
-- A typeclass which different types may implement.
class Prop p where
  valid         :: p -> Bool            -- Same thing as a Tautism
  contradiction :: p -> Bool            -- False under all conditions/opposite of Tautism
  lequiv        :: p -> p -> Bool
```

What we're doing here is creating a new *typeclass* called **Prop**. We need the syntax `Prop p` because we need to define the behaviour of an instance `p` of the `Prop` class. If we don't introduce a symbol for it, then how will the compiler know what we're talking about the in the typeclass definition? For example, the line `valid :: p -> Bool` says that for every instance `p` of typeclass `Prop`, there must be a method called `valid` which maps `p` to a boolean value. Likewise, there must be a similar method for `contradiction`.

Now the line `lequiv :: p -> p -> Bool` may cause some confusion because `p` appears twice. It's important to understand that `p`, being an *instance of a typeclass*, is a **type**. There are no "objects" as in object-oriented languages. Remember: `p` is a **type** which satisfies the typeclass **contract** given by `Prop`. The Java equivalent would be a class `p` implementing an interface `Prop`. What we're saying here is that for type which implements/is a part of this typeclass `Prop`, there is a method called `lequiv` of comparing them. And its type is `p -> p -> Bool` meaning that it takes in two expressions of type `p` and returns a boolean indicating whether or not they're equivalent.

---

### Boolean Instance Definition

All we've told the compiler so far are our promises: there will be methods for checking whether an instance of `Prop` is *valid* or a *contradiction*, and a method for comparing two propositions of the same type for equality.

To start, we implement these procedures for the most basic type of proposition: one that is just `True` or `False`.

```
-- This is a proposition which is simply a literal Bool!
instance Prop Bool where
  valid         = id
  contradiction = not
  lequiv b1 b2  = b1 == b2
```

Here, `Prop Bool` says that in the expression `Prop p` above, the type whose behaviour/implementation we're defining is the `Bool` type. How do we check if a `Bool` is valid? Well, it takes no arguments, so a proposition that is just `True` or `False` is valid if it's true, and otherwise a contradiction.

1. `valid = id` says that the function `valid` mapping our proposition type of `Bool` to whether or not it's a valid formula is the function `id`. (This function just returns whatever it's given).
2. `contradiction = not` says that the function `contradiction` mapping the proposition type `Bool` to whether or not it's a contradiction is the function `not`. Just as well, because `not` takes just one `Bool` as an argument, and returns a `Bool`. This is compatible with the contract we laid out earlier in the *typeclass* definition of `Prop`.
3. `lequiv b1 b2 = (b1 == b2)` says that the way of comparing two of these propositions (once again, of type `Bool` here) for logical equivalence is to simply invoke the already existing method `==`.

---

### Inductive Instance Definition - First Step

This is the fun part. We're using induction. Here's the full code snippet, and then I'll break down each line.

```
instance (Prop p) => Prop (Bool -> p) where
  valid f         = (valid (f True)) && (valid (f False))
  lequiv f g      = (lequiv (f True) (g True)) && (lequiv (f False) (g False))
  contradiction f = (contradiction $ f True) && (contradiction $ f False)
```

Now the first line says this: `(Bool -> p)` is of type `Prop`, as long as the constraints in what we call the **context** are met. Here the context is what comes before the `=>`, and what it says is that `p`, the type, is a member of the `Prop` typeclass. This means that we're saying that any type which maps a `Bool` to **any** type of `Prop` is itself an instance of `Prop`. Why are we doing this? Well, let's start with the simplest case.

`Bool` is an instance of typeclass `Prop`, because we defined this 'base case' explicitly. Okay, so then `(Bool -> Bool)` is also of typeclass prop, because we said that any type `(Bool -> <something in class Prop>)` is in class `Prop`. This gives us the functions which take in one boolean argument and return a boolean. Examples: `not`, `id`, `(\a -> True)`, `(\a -> False)`. (In fact, these are all such functions).

How have we defined whether to determine whether one of these functions is `valid`? Our definition says that

```
valid f = (valid (f True)) && (valid (f False))
```

It says that a boolean function `f` of one boolean is valid if and only if `(f True)` and `(f False)` are both valid. Of course, the validity of boolean is just that boolean. So in this case, `valid` can be thought of as being a bit simpler:

```
valid f = (f True) && (f False)
```

Alright, so `f` is valid if and only if it evaluates to `True` for both arguments! That's what we want.

Now for `contradiction`:

```
contradiction f = (contradiction $ f True) && (contradiction $ f False)
```

This is the key: `contradiction` asks the question "*Is this proposition **false** for **all possible inputs***"? To test this, we split `f` into two parts: its first argument and the rest. If the first argument is `True`, then is it possible to *satisfy* proposition `f` with the remaining arguments? If not, then it's a contradiction. This is the part `contradiction $ f True`.

`f True` is itself a function of 1 Bool argument, so it is in class `Prop`, and so we're able to apply `contradiction` to it to see if it's a contradiction. We also need to be sure that it's not possible to satisfy `f` if the first argument is `False` either, which is why we `&&` this with `contradiction $ f False`.

I'll leave the `lequiv` function as an exercise, and move on to the next inductive step.

### Inductive Instance Definition - Inception

Since `(Bool -> Bool)` is of class `Prop`, then so too is `Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)`. I could be mistake, but I'm fairly sure that `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` is actually just short-hand for this. So this means that a boolean function of two boolean variables is itself a proposition. How do we determine its validity? We check if both `f True` and `f False` are valid. The former means 'if `f True False` and `f True True` both evaluate to True'.

Hopefully you can see now the recursion that's going on (I haven't done a great job explaining it; sorry)-- what we're doing is recursively defining the `valid`ity of the type `Bool -> Bool -> .... -> Bool` so that such a function is valid if and only if it evaluates to `True` for all possible inputs.

Comment: You have masterfully avoided going in the detail of the only line of code you have really changed from my question to your answer :)

Comment: @Boris - Sorry, which line is that? Apart from a typo I corrected, I don't recall there being any differences.

Comment: You explained everything that the textbook explained, and left answering my question as exercise :)

Comment: @Boris - I added a bit to **Inductive Instance Definition - First Step**.

Comment: @Boris - My definition of `contradiction` is functionally the same as yours; I've just used some different syntactic sugar.

Comment: So the code is fine as it is, and it does what I think it did? I am still a bit unsure as to why to use `not` instead of `False`, and if one of the two is actually wrong.

Comment: `FlexibleInstances` are there because the book says so :/

Comment: @Boris - Yes, the code does what you think it did. I only use `not` instead because it looks neater/cleaner. It is important that you understand that for a `Bool` type, `b == False` is exactly the same as `not b`.

Comment: Alright, I finally see the light. It is a very well written answer; thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: @Boris -  If I had more time, I would have written a shorter answer. Thank you for the question; I've since built upon the example and added operators like `==>` and the `forall` and `exists` quantifiers acting on enumerable sets of propositions.

Comment: FWIW in the typesignature `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` isn't equivalent to `Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)` the point is that **currying** (or partially applying) a function of type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` results in a function of type `Bool -> Bool` which is what matches the `Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)` typesignature. This is what actually makes your code work. It's what you're using in the definition of `contradiction`

Comment: @Vogel612 - The compiler does currying, making these typesignatures essentially equivalent for all purposes, no?